# Reference for de Rham cohomology for physicists

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, noncommutative-geometry

Do  you  know  a  basic  reference  to  introduce an  undergraduate  student  with  more  physical  rather  than  mathematical  background  to   De Rham  cohomology?

The Student (from a  Bachelors  program  in material science) should  work  on  a  summer project  aiming  to  understand  some  of  the mathematics  behind  the  quantum hall efect,  explained  with chern  numbers. The   student  has  previously helped  on experiments  with  some  materials relevant  to  the  quantum  hall  efect.

I  do  know  the  mathematical ellaborations  on this  ranging  von Bellisard, Schulz-Baldes,  collaborators   and  Connes'approach   on the  topic  in the  noncommutative  geometry  book. This  will  be  certanily  too  advanced  from the  point  of  view  of  mathematics.

Comment: What about an elementary differential geometry textbook? (I am thinking of a mixture of chapters from Lee's differentiable manifolds plus the appendix of Milnor-Stasheff for the characteristic classes material). Would that also be too advanced?

Comment: I like the book "From Calculus to Cohomology" by Madsen and Tornehave for this sort of thing, as well as the "Topology, Geometry, and Gauge Fields" series by Naber.  But starting with nothing and getting through de Rham cohomology in one summer feels ambitious, let alone the quantum hall effect.

Comment: Why is this appropriate on MO rather than on MSE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with some topological field theory, then the de Rham cohomology of $M$ can be viewed as the vector space of supersymmetric vacua in the $\sigma$-model associated to $M$. I think this was first noted by Prof. Witten in his work on sypersymmetry and Morse theory. You can look it up in the paragraph 4 of chapter 10 [here](http://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01c.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I think the book you want is Frankel's *The Geometry of Physics:  An Introduction*.   It's accessible and well written, and largely aimed at the material you're talking about.